# Python - Datetime Issue

Tags: python, datetime

This should be a simple fix, but I can not figure out why I keep getting this error:

```
DATE = '8/27/2012 19:12:00'
Convert = datetime.strptime(DATE, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')


ValueError: time data '8/27/2012 19:12:00' does not match format '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S'
```

Am I missing something? does the month need to be "08"?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your day and month are flipped; month can't take a value of 27:

```
>>> convert = datetime.strptime(DATE, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
>>> convert
datetime.datetime(2012, 8, 27, 19, 12)
```

Comment: @JeffSaltfist You may consider accepting the answer if it helped :)

Comment: Yes, sorry for the delay.